# Any other major difference between iPhone and iPod Touch except telephone function?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

Any major difference between iPhone and iPod Touch except telephone function?

What does the iPhone have but the iPod Touch doesn't have and vice versa?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The differences aside from design, size, glass back cover and weight is that the iPod touch has:

1. No cellular data
2. No GPS, cell tower, or other non-WiFi Location data
3. The iPod touch is not available with a 16Gb HD, only 8, 32, or 64.
4. No Digital Compass
5. Display is not fingerprint resistant
6. Video is 720p on iPod and 1080p on iPhone
7. Still photos are .6 megapixels in the iPod and 8 megapixels on iPhone
8. No image stabilisation in video mode
9. No Siri
10. 256Mb RAM compared with 512Mb
11. £330 more in your pocket.
12. previous generation CPU (A4 vs A5)
13. less support (1 free support phone call vs 3)
14. no LED flash for camera
15. no vibration function
16. USB power adapter not included
17. headphones have no remote/mic

This compares the most upto date iPod Touch (4th gen) with the most upto date iPhone (4S) at time of writing

12-17 were added after Ken suggested more. +1 to Ken for spotting the additional differences.

Comment: An iPod touch does have limited location data using the wifi triangulation/base station ID mojo.

Answer (score 3):

Graeme got most of them, but here are a couple more I've noticed about the iPod Touch:

- previous generation CPU (A4 vs A5)
- less support (1 free support phone call vs 3)
- no LED flash for camera
- no vibrator
- USB power adapter not included ($30 extra)
- headphones have no remote/mic

Comment: +1 from me for the additions. will add to answer and credit

Answer (score 2):

So far, between iPhone 4 and iPod Touch the minuses (on iPod side) are:

- No phone
- No 3G/CSDMA/GPRS
- No GPS

Comment: Without being told otherwise, would have to assume the current gen of each, so add lower quality camera, slower CPU, less RAM to the mix

Comment: @stuffe - Due to CPU and GPU differences I wouldn't dare comparing the iPod to 4S. iPhone 4 is still being sold by able (though only available with 8GB of storage).

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, there's the Siri functionality that's currently limited to the 4S.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, we have found that the battery in our iPhone 4S lasts longer than the battery in our 4th gen iPod Touch.  From what I can find, it seems that the 4S has a 1,432mAh battery, while the Touch only has a 930mAh.

Comment: You will see that Apple states the battery will last 40 hours of audio playback on both devices. That is teh only fair way to campare by using a feature both models suport.

Comment: It does.  And you will also see that these same specs list 10 hours of video playback for the 4S but 7 hours for iPod Touch.  So, not surprising, what you do makes a difference.  For much of what we do, the 4S lasts longer.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: You are right, it totally depends what you are doing, however if you have 3G and location data enabled then the iPhone will suck away more battery than the iPod as the iPod doesn't have these power leaches to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember reading about this correctly some time ago, the displays, while both having "Retina" resolution, are different models from different OEM sources. The iPhone display is allegedly somewhat brighter with better colors than the one on the iPod touch. I don't have a reference for this, but you can Google it.

Comment: The iPhone 4 (and iPhone 4S) have a state of the art IPS display, whereas the iPod Touch merely has a normal TFT display.  Both are considered "Retina", but it's a pretty startling improvement when you see the iPhone 4(S) IPS display.  The IPS is better in every way, chief among those being the viewable angle.